# can't delete item from collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have simple collectionview which shows 1 column on iphone and 2 columns on iPad

There is a button which removing an item from collectionview but when I press the button I got this error:

> The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (4), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

And this is my code

```
protocol AudioListDataProtocol: class {
    func search(searchText: String)
    func playComposition(composition: Composition, data: [Composition], play: Bool)
    func endEditing()
}

class AudioListDataAdapter: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate, AudioItemCellProtocol {
    var delegate: AudioListDataProtocol!
    var isFavoriesList = false

    private var data = [Composition]()
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    private let cellIdentifier = "AudioCellIdent"
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath!
    private var cellWidth = 0 as CGFloat
    private var sectionCount = 0
    private var itemCount = 0


    //MARK: public methods
    func initSearchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Void {
        self.searchBar = searchBar
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        self.searchBar.placeholder = DicionaryManager.shared.getStringValue(dKey: AMKeys.mobile_label_search_here)
    }

    func initCollection(collection: UICollectionView) -> Void {
        self.collectionView = collection
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "AudioItemCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    func setListData(data: [Composition], itemsPerSection: Int, itemWidth: CGFloat) -> Void {
        cellWidth = itemWidth
        self.data = data
        itemCount = itemsPerSection
        sectionCount = Int(ceil(Double(self.data.count / itemCount)))
    }

    func reload() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    //MARK: UISearchBarDelegate
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.characters.count >= 3 {
            if let d = delegate {
                d.search(searchText: searchText)
            }
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = ""
        if let d = delegate {
            d.search(searchText: "")
            d.endEditing()
        }
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if let d = delegate {
            d.endEditing()
        }
    }


    //MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return sectionCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemCount
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AudioItemCell {
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let c = cell as! AudioItemCell
        c.setupComposition(composition: data[curItemIndex(indexPath: indexPath)])
        c.indexPath = indexPath
        c.favoriteState = isFavoriesList
        c.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        PlayerManager.shared.changePlaylist()
        var item: Composition
        item = data[curItemIndex(indexPath: indexPath)] as Composition
        item.isPlaying = true
        item.showPlayer = true
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        delegate.playComposition(composition: item, data: data, play: true)
    }

    func playingCompositionForReload(composition: Composition) {
        composition.isPlaying = true
        composition.showPlayer = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 90)
    }


    //MARK: helpers methods
    func updateState(play: Bool) -> Void {
        if (selectedIndexPath) != nil {
            let item = data[curItemIndex(indexPath: selectedIndexPath)]
            item.isPlaying = !item.isPlaying
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let item = data[0]
            item.isPlaying = true
            item.showPlayer = true
        }

        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [selectedIndexPath])
    }   


    private func curItemIndex(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
        return indexPath.section * itemCount + indexPath.item
    }


    //MARK: AudioItemCellProtocol
    func removeCellAtIndexpath(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.data.remove(at: self.curItemIndex(indexPath: indexPath))
            sectionCount = Int(ceil(Double(self.data.count / self.itemCount)))
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And this button pressed code

```
delegate.removeCellAtIndexpath(indexPath: indexPath)
```

What I did wrong here and why its crashing?

Please help I stuck on this a day.

Comment: Can you please correct the spelling of "secrtionCount" ? ;-)

Comment: @onnoweb I fixed it. Please tell me my problem if you can

Comment: my guess is after `self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])` put `self.itemCount -= 1`, I can't build your code now...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `numberOfItemsInSection` method and the use of the `itemCount` property. You are returning a fixed number. You are assuming every section has the same fixed number of items. Instead, you should be returning the current number of records in your data source for the given section.

It would help a lot if you setup your data source to be an array of arrays where the outer array represents your sections and each inner array is the items in that section. Then you simply return the array count instead of some predetermined variable.

Comment: hmmm. Wise solution. There isn't any solution exactly on my code? Sorry for that man ((